# How to join/connect between row in Contact Form DB with Multistep form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created Multistep form using Contact Form 7 & Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms. Then I want to save to DB so I use Contact Form DB.
I found there's no connection ID between rows of DB tables. There's no primary key ID or foreign key for form. How to connect form data from which I fill consecutively?

[image]

[image]

[image]